Alternative semantics for first-order logic
The standard semantics for classical first-order logic is well-known. We have a domain of discourse, which is a set (some authors say empty, some say non-empty). Relation symbols are interpreted as sets of tuples. Function symbols are interpreted as sets of tuples. Constants are interpreted as individuals or as nullary functions. Free variables are treated as ranging over elements in the domain, which gives us a natural notion of what a parameter is.
This semantics is very natural and first-order logic is itself very natural. I think about many other logics by mapping them back to FOL in a way that preserves their consequence relation.
What are the different possible semantics for the first-order logic?
I'm deliberately leaving it vague what exactly a semantics is. Also, these semantics shouldn't be different in the sense that they induce a different consequence relation. I take the standard consequence relation as the thing that I'm trying to model.
Off the top of my head, I can think of the following. These are just ideas that I am aware of. I don't mean to preclude the possibility of an answer mentioning them.

The standard semantics.
Game semantics, $\exists$ is the player, $\forall$ is the environment, $\lor$ is a player-owned choice between two games, $\land$ is an environment-owned choice between two games, $\lnot$ exchanges the role of the player and the environment.
Proof-theoretic semantics is mentioned in a comment on this question, although I admittedly don't understand it.
You can construct a Tarski-Lindenbaum algebra by taking cylindric algebra and generalizing it so it can handle more than just quantifiers and equality, but I don't know how satisfying the result would be. At the very least, the obvious generalization will be able to handle the fragment of FOL with relations and constants but no functions.

I'm also dimly aware that you can endow first-order logic with a categorical interpretation or a computational one, but I don't know the details.

There is a useful if somewhat dated article by Hugues Leblanc in the Handbook of Phil Logic, vol 1 (first ed.) on 'Alternatives to Standard First-Order Semantics'. There he distinguishes between standard semantics, substitutional semantics, truth-value semantics and probabilistic semantics.
All the non-standard semantics interpret the universal quantifier substitutionally , that is, a universal quantification is true iff every substitution instance is true. Substitutional semantics is defined over a restricted class of standard models, called Henkin-models. Truth-value semantics and probabilistic semantics abandon models entirely, opting for truth-value assignments and probability assignments, respectively, instead.
